# How to select the answer if the two players answer at the same time

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I have a game online using Firebase database using Swift 4
The game is a general information question and depends on the speed of the answer
The problem is if the two players answer at the same time and he calculates or select the answer for all the players but I want to calculate or select the answer to only one player
What is the appropriate trick or code?

Comment: take time in nano seconds to track who pressed first then there will be very low possibility of pressing on same time.

Comment: The foremost issue is that your response timings will be based on internet lag. You will have to have some way to record the actual time of the press and it cannot be based on when Firebase receives the data as my 300 baud modem would lag way behind your fiber connection. You also cannot rely on the time in the device. I would suggest your app record the time the question was received by the device and calculate how long it took to answer based on that received time. You then have a realistic time comparison. Having two players take exactly the same time is probably not going to happen.

Answer (score 1):

This problem can be seen as a mutual exclusion problem and you should do some concurrency control to perform this transaction in case you do not permit "draws" in your game.

Is kind of hard to receive two taps at the very same time. What you can do about is record the time in the lowest possible scale - nanoseconds maybe - and decide which was sent first. If the time is equal on both sides you should wether accept or deny both submissions.

Comment: Thank you for that , Can you give me simple code for that

Answer (score 0):

in that case one will not be recored,thats why you a have a method by firebase in to use in this kind of situition

from firebase DOC

> When working with data that could be corrupted by concurrent
>   modifications, such as incremental counters, you can use a transaction
>   operation. You give this operation two arguments: an update function
>   and an optional completion callback. The update function takes the
>   current state of the data as an argument and returns the new desired
>   state you would like to write

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write

Answer (score 0):

Save your data in millisecond timestamps, then compare them.
Don't forget to take into consideration the timezones of players.